# Excel VBA Looping a continuous copy/paste with delay

Tags: vba, excel, loops, delay

I already have code below which successfully copy and pastes one row on Sheet1 to the next open row on Sheet2.  The data on this row is imported from an external application and updates constantly, thereby creating a history writer.  I have attempted several methods to loop this action with a delay and have failed.

GOAL: Loop this code with .25 second delay with the option to exit the loop with a button click or key-press.  The delay is more important than the exit condition as I can just Esc if need be.

```
Private Sub START_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    copySheet.Range("A23:L23").Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Start_Click` event to run another procedure, with a module-level variable that flags whether user has requested to Stop the procedure. You'll need to use WinAPI `Sleep` function with a 250ms delay because `Application.OnTime` (which is commonly used to schedule a procedure to run at a future time) will not work with fractions of seconds. You will not be able to really "interact" with Excel while this procedure is running:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Dim bRunContinuously As Boolean
Private Sub START_Click()
    bRunContinuously = True
    While bRunContinuously
        Call Do_Stuff
        Sleep 250
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
Private Sub STOP_Click()
    bRunContinuously = False
    Debug.Print "Stopped!"
End Sub

Sub Do_Stuff()
    Dim dest As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dest =  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    With copySheet.Range("A23:L23")
       dest.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for that Sleep function, I'm adding it to my toolkit!

Comment: @Matt Note it's different than Application.Wait -- look up the dox on both to see how they differ :)

Comment: Excellent thank you!!!  I had to revert back to the .Pastespecial xlPasteValues from my original code and changed the declaration to Private and 64bit but that is my fault for not stating it to start with.  As always great support from a great community thanks guys!

Comment: Okay perhaps I spoke too soon.  The cell values no longer update.  I assume because  the wait time is holding all other excel functions.  I should add that I am using the Excel RTD function for these values.  The loop copies but it just keeps copying the same values and excel rtd no longer updates the values.

Comment: Nevermind, solved with Excel.Application.RTD.RefreshData

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application. Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")/4)` that should do the trick.  TimeValue only drops to 1 second by design so dividing by 4 gets you to 0.25 seconds.  That's the easiest way to pause your code in 1 line.

BUT after timing the function it doesn't look to give you consistent time delays.  I like the Sleep presented in another answer by @David Zemens which is very consistent.  Here's some test code:

```
'These go ABOVE your function
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub testwait()

StartTime = GetTickCount
Sleep 250
EndTime = GetTickCount
MsgBox ((EndTime - StartTime) & " milliseconds")

End Sub
```

You then could call your function in a loop with that `Sleep` function.  Or just use the built in `Application.Wait` if you don't need super precise time delays.  As David pointed out to me, they are different - `Sleep` will freeze Excel while running http://analystcave.com/vba-sleep-vs-wait/ while `Application.Wait` will allow you to Esc out of the macro.

Comment: I think you're on the right track but probably OP wants `Application.OnTime` method to schedule the procedure to run again (and again, and again, until some condition breaks the loop), rather than `Application.Wait`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if `OnTime` allows for fractional seconds and a quick test suggests that it does not.

Comment: Yes the sleep works flawlessly, it should be noted however that even though I am using Sleep 250, I sometimes only get 3 readings per second.  I am using Excel RTD so I can only assume that the data feed, excel, the macro or all three lag ever so slightly (i.e. a few milliseconds at most).  Sometimes I get 3 readings per second sometimes 4 although this is more than enough data needed for my purposes.  As always with the stack, thank you gentlemen for your timely and informative responses.  Solved.